# terraform private endpoint private dns zone not able to populate

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-private-dns

i have following code to create private endpoint, and if provided, will be associated with a private dns zone as well, however, the private endpoint is crated ignoring private dns zone value I entered, treat it as Null resource. I'm not sure what went wrong inside the dynamic block

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "this" {
  name                = join("", [lookup(var.service_subresource_map, "name"), "-pvt-endpoint"])
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.endpoint_subnet.id
  tags                = var.tags

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = join("", [lookup(var.service_subresource_map, "name"), "-pvt-endpoint-conn"])
    private_connection_resource_id = lookup(var.service_subresource_map, "resource_id")
    subresource_names              = [lookup(var.service_subresource_map, "subresource_name")]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  dynamic "private_dns_zone_group" {
    for_each = var.private_dns_zone_group[*]

    content {
      name                 = private_dns_zone_group.value.name
      private_dns_zone_ids = private_dns_zone_group.value.private_dns_zone_ids
    }
  }
```

the value I provided in private_dns_zone_group is this

```
private_dns_zone_group = {
    name = "private-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [
      "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rogertest/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/example.com",
    ]
  }
```

and variable is as following

```
variable "private_dns_zone_group" {
 
  type = object({
    name                 = string
    private_dns_zone_ids = list(string)
  })
  default = null
}
```

everything is deployed without error except for private dns zone association

if I replace dynamic block with simple block like this

```
private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "private-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [
      "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rogertest/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/example.com",
    ]
  }
```

then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your service , if you want to use Private Endpoint then you will have to properly name as per the naming convention for the Private DNS Zones which can referred from this ***[`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#azure-services-dns-zone-configuration)*** . For example , If you are creating ***Private Endpoint*** for `App Service`, `Storage` and `SQL` , then your ***Private DNS Group*** will have ***Id's of Zones with names*** :
***`['privatelink.azurewebsites.net','privatelink.blob.core.windows.net','privatelink.database.windows.net']`***.

**I tested the same for only app service by using your code :**

`.tfvars`

```
private_dns_zone_group = {
    name                 = "private-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [
      "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.azurewebsites.net"
    ]
}
```

`Main.tf`

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

variable "private_dns_zone_group" {
 
  type = object({
    name                 = string
    private_dns_zone_ids = list(string)
  })
  default = null
}
data "azurerm_subnet" "endpoint_subnet" {
  name                 = "default"
  virtual_network_name = "ansuman-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "xxxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "this" {
  name                = "appservice-pvt-endpoint"
  location            = "west us 2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_subnet.endpoint_subnet.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.endpoint_subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           =  "appservice-pvt-endpoint-conn"
    private_connection_resource_id = "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ansumantestapp"
    subresource_names              = ["sites"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  dynamic "private_dns_zone_group" {
    for_each = var.private_dns_zone_group[*]

    content {
      name                 = private_dns_zone_group.value.name
      private_dns_zone_ids = private_dns_zone_group.value.private_dns_zone_ids
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

- Please make sure you have the latest versions of ***`Azurerm Provider`*** and ***`Terraform`*** .
- If you are still getting the error then try removing the default
  argument from the Private DNS group variable block:

  ```
  variable "private_dns_zone_group" {

    type = object({
      name                 = string
      private_dns_zone_ids = list(string)
    })
    default = null ## remove this argument
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT, thanks for that, What I'm trying to do is use a pre-created, existing private dns zone, so not using default name for this resource. Also, I tried taken off null default value, now it complains that " no definition is found", so almost like it can not read that particular tfvar value...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the reason.. I put resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "this" as a module, when I'm calling the module, I forgot to include private_dns_zone_group = var.private_dns_zone_group

so of course, it's always missing the tfvar value.... always something so simple...